# Numerical integration for $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

> **Problem**: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of 5th degree (or less) then show that $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{18}\left\{5f(\alpha) + 8f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + 5f(\beta)\right\}$$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of $x^{2} - x + (1/10) = 0$.

My approach is of verification in the sense that I first establish that if the formula holds for $f(x), g(x)$ then it holds for a linear combination $af(x) + bg(x)$ and then verify the result for each of the function $f(x) = 1, x, x^{2}, \cdots, x^{5}$.

However this approach of verification is entirely unsatisfactory. The result seems to be a higher order numerical integration formula adapted for $\int_{0}^{1}$ instead of the general $\int_{a}^{b}$. It also reminds me of the Simpson's rule $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx = \frac{b - a}{6}\left\{f(a) + 4f\left(\frac{a + b}{2}\right) + f(b) \right\} - \frac{(b - a)^{5}}{2880}f^{(4)}(c)$$ for some $c \in (a, b)$ which shows that it is exact for polynomials of degree 3 or less.

Also the numbers $\alpha, \beta$ as roots of $x^{2} - x + (1/10) = 0$ seem to be totally mysterious. Please provide a better way to prove this formula (similar to the way Simpson's rule can be proved) which naturally leads to the constants $\alpha, \beta$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of
[Gaussian
quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature).  The sample points at $1/2$ and $1/2 \pm \sqrt{15}/10$
are the roots of $(x-\frac12)(x^2-x+\frac1{10})$, which is the third orthogonal
polynomial for integration on $[0,1]$ (i.e. the monic multiple of
$P_3(2x-1)$ where $P_3$ is the third
 
[Legendre polynomial)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality).

Comment: I will check the wikipedia articles you refer. Can you please explain a bit more and show why need to consider Legendre polynomial for $P_{3}(2x - 1) = (x - 1/2)(x^{2} - x + 1/10)$ for integration on interval $[0, 1]$. I am only familiar with Trapezoidal and Simpson's rule for numerical integration and don't have much idea of the techniques you refer.

Comment: Also from Wikipedia I see that a quadrature based on $P_{n}(x)$ is exact for polynomials upto degree $(2n - 1)$. Is there any reference available which provides a proof and many details of Gaussian quadrature?

Comment: The full explanation is too long for a **stackexchange** answer.  
That's why I linked to the Wikipedia pages.  If Wikipedia and Mathworld
do not explain adequately, try the references they give.

Comment: Yeah I can understand one can not present a full topic in an answer to a question here. I will check if any of the references are available online.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine.  There is really no difference in integrating from $0$ to $1$ or from $a$ to $b$.  You just do the transformation $x \in [0,1] \to y \in [a,b]$ by $y=a+(b-a)x$ and the linearity makes the same proof go through.

The derivation of $\alpha , \beta$ is from doing this proof.  You just do it with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as parameters.  The coefficients $\frac 5{18}, \frac 8{18}$ are equally mysterious, but you just do the calculation with these parameters as unknowns and choose them so all the powers of $x$ in $f(x)$ are accounted for, as high as you can go.